# Emtpy shares with SMB/Samba with option "smb encrypt=desired"

Tags: macos, catalina, encryption, smb

If I connect with my MBP (macOS Catalina 10.15.3) to a SMB/Samba share without the option "smb encrypt=desired" on the server side everything works well. Smbstatus says SMB3_02, encryption is turned off and signing shows AES-128-CMAC.

With the option "smb encrypt=desired" on the server side smbstatus shows SMB3_02 and encryption and signing with AES-128-CMAC.

However, the share seems to be empty. After some minutes Finder says that the original object for "sharename" can't be found. I also can't disconnect anymore, as Finder says that the share can't be disconnected being still in use. Then Finder is not responsive and a restart of Finder is necessary.

Does anyone know any solution to this? It seems to me, that this problem is related to Apple's implementation of SMB.

Comment: server runs debian with samba 4.5.16

Comment: solved by upgrading samba 4.9.5.